# Polymer 1.0 property value reset to default

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

this is my second round with Polymer. This time I got an object property bound to a form's set of inputs. I run an `iron-ajax` request to send a json object obtained by the form and I got this object back with few changes, I add an identifier to object. Everything goes fine, I send the json and got it back with id value, but as response function completes property is set back to default value, as page was reloaded. [Here](https://github.com/fpezzati/yomoka_client) you can find my dummy app code. There is another branch, `with-iron-input`, where I tried to achieve my goal using `iron-input` instead of plain old `input` elements, of course I got the same behaviour. What did I miss?

**update:** the page is reloaded. I update my app adding a list of element to it. List's items are loaded by json mock and are correctly displayed, but when I try to do a PUT, as response comes back default values are showed, empty list too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.
My component looks like this:

```
<form>
  <iron-ajax ...></iron-ajax>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="offerId">Id</label><input id="offerId" type="text" value="{{offer._id::input}}"></input><br>
    ...
  </fieldset>
  <button on-tap="offerReset">New</button>
  <button on-tap="offerSubmit">Send</button>
  ...
</form>
```

and as I said in question, when I hit the `Send` button, I got back data but page was reloaded. I remove the `form` tag this way:

```
<iron-ajax ...></iron-ajax>
<fieldset>
  <label for="offerId">Id</label><input id="offerId" type="text" value="{{offer._id::input}}"></input><br>
  ...
</fieldset>
<button on-tap="offerReset">New</button>
<button on-tap="offerSubmit">Send</button>
...
```

and now component behaves as expected. I also update the GitHub repo.